# SQL: Find a value based on effective date

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table of employees and another table showing their role history. The history table has an effective date from when the role started. Finding an employees current role is trivial, but I am having issues finding their role at a certain point in time.

```
Example:

Table: Employee History

Columns: EmployeeID
         Effective Date
         Role

Sample Records: [ABC123, 1/4/2013, Developer]
                [ABC123, 6/9/2013, Designer]
                [DEF456. 8/5/2013, Manager]


Table: Event

Columns: EventID
         Date
         EmployeeID
         Event Type

Sample Records: [1, 6/6/2013, ABC123, BOOKED_HOURS]
                [2, 6/9/2013, ABC123, BOOKED_LEAVE]
                [3, 8/5/2013, DEF456, SICK_LEAVE]
```

I then have another table showing a series of events that have happened over time and want to see what the employees role was at the time of the event taking place. I would like to be able to do this using plain SQL rather than a function.

The Result set I am after is something like:

```
[6/6/2013, ABC123, Developer, BOOKED_HOURS]
[6/9/2013, ABC123, Designer, BOOKED_LEAVE]
[8/5/2013, DEF456, Manager, SICK_LEAVE]
```

It can be safely assumed that an Employee will always have a role, i.e. they cannot create events without a role.

I have been wracking my brain on this for far too long as it is, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select e.*,
       (select top 1 eh.Role
        from EmployeeHistory eh
        where e.EmployeeId = eh.EmployeeId and
              e.date >= eh.EffectiveDate
        order by eh.EffectiveDate desc
       ) as Role
from Event e;
```